# Play Framework Bootstrap Webjar integration not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, playframework, playframework-2.3

Hi I try to integrate play framework (current) 2.3.7 with Bootstrap 3:

sbt file:

```html
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.3.0-2",
  "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.1.1-2"
)
```

html

```html
<body>
    

            <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='@routes.Assets.at(WebJarAssets.locate("css/bootstrap.min.css"))'>

      

        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Only throws this error:
[MultipleMatchesException: Multiple matches found for css/bootstrap.min.css. Please provide a more specific path, for example by including a version number.]

a different try (which should have worked on earlier 2.3 versions):
http://www.webjars.org/documentation

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='@routes.WebJarAssets.at(WebJarAssets.locate("css/bootstrap.min.css"))'>
<script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.WebJarAssets.at(WebJarAssets.locate("jquery.min.js"))'></script>
```

But Play only tells me that the web jar assets controller is not available

```html
value WebJarAssets is not a member of object controllers.routes
```

can someone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: this seems to work --> but does not seem correct? -->  what is the right / best approach?
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='@routes.Assets.at("/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css")'>


I try to get something like:
https://github.com/knoldus/playing-reactive-mongo/blob/master/app/views/main.scala.html but:
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.WebJarAssets.at(WebJarAssets.locate("bootswatch-united", "bootstrap.min.css"))">

does not work --> as stated in the question.

Comment: Is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22242605/how-to-use-webjars-loader-plugin correct?

Comment: Why did you use code snippets everywhere?  They are of no use here and clutter the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have an entry in your routes file for the WebJarAssets controller? Something like this:

```
GET     /webjars/*file                    controllers.WebJarAssets.at(file)
```

Comment: sure but:  Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET        /assets/*file        controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
there seems to be a difference: Assets instead of WebJarAssets.

Comment: The entry for Assets is fine, but to locate the WebJars you need an additional routes entry. That's why you're getting the "WebJarAssets is not a member of ..." error, because you're using it here "@routes.WebJarAssets" without having declared it in the routes.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I got the error:

```
value WebJarAssets is not a member of object controllers.routes
```

even though I had added

```
GET     /webjars/*file     controllers.WebJarAssets.at(file)
```

to the routes file.

`sbt clean` did not help. I ended up with `git clean -f -d -x` which removes everything not tracked by git. Then it compiled.

Answer (score 1):

You simply use the Assets controller to access WebJars, they are extracted by Play automatically to the target/lib folder. You can refer to them via @routes.Assets.at(“lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css”).